# How can I capture the inserted value in contenteditable element?

Tags: html, event-handling, user-input

I'm wondering how I can capture the recently inserted value of a contenteditable. I have

```
<section id="content" contenteditable="true">
</section>

<script>
  function parse(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  var el = document.getElementById("content");
  el.addEventListener("input", parse, false);
</script>
```

It seems as though the event doesn't carry any information regarding what content was just inserted. Is there another "out-of-the-box" method that could capture this? I'm not very familiar with mutation events, but is that perhaps my best shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this may be a poor-mans solution, but hooking it up with a keypress event listener gave me the keycode for the recently pressed key

```
function doKeyPress(e) {
  console.log(e.keycode)
}

var el = document.getElementById("content");
el.addEventListener("keypress", doKeyPress, false);
```

Just a matter of mapping keycodes to values to get there.